# How to determine if room number is in database or not

Tags: php

I need help on my php, I don't know how to do this but what I want is the user to enter in a room number in a textbox and when the user submits the form, if the room number is not in the database then it should display a message stating room is invalid. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Below is relevant code:

Javascript code for validation:

```
         function validation() {

           var isDataValid = true;

        var roomTextO = document.getElementById("room"); 

    //this retrieves an element from the textbox where user enters in a room number

        var errRoomMsgO = document.getElementById("roomAlert");

     // this is where the alert message appears for validation



   if (roomTextO.value == ""){
          errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Enter in a Room Number";
          isDataValid = false;
        }else if (!trimmedRoomText.length){
          errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = "Please Enter in a Room Number"; 
          isDataValid = false;      
    }else{
                errRoomMsgO.innerHTML = ""; 
        }

        }
```

Below is relevant SQL where room numbers are stored in database:

```
<?php

    $roomresult = mysql_query( "SELECT Room FROM Room" );

?>
```

The name of the Table is "Room" and the Room numbers are stored under the field "Room".

Below is the textbox where user enters in room number:

```
<p><strong>Room:</strong> <input type="text" id="room" name="roomChosen" /><br/><span id="roomAlert"></span></p>      <!-- Enter Room here-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to select by the room_id (or some other criteria[s] that will deliver a unique result) basic sql, really...

```
$roomresult = mysql_query( "SELECT Room FROM Room WHERE Room_Id = " . (int) $_POST['roomChosen']);
```

Comment: Ok so really last part of question is how can I mention in my javascript validation when if room number isn't in database then display message stating room is invalid?

Comment: you're approaching the problem from the wrong side (quite literally) php checks (via mysql) if the room is available so you can/have to give the message when you render the page, you can - of course - put some hidden information on the page if the room is available or not and depending on that do some JS Magic to do something, but why all the hassle?

Comment: It is because I have done all of my validation through javascript. i have an included an example of a javascript validation in my question above where if textbox is empty then display the message "Enter a Room Number" else don't display anything. I want something similar with this validation where room number is not in database